# how to set column in center position

Tags: c#, center

Well, I used this code to named a column,

```
listView1.Columns.Add("x").Width =100;
```

How to make 'x' column appear in Center position?

Comment: I'm not sure that is valid syntax, but setting the column width wont center the elements within it.  Is this WPF, Winforms or ASP?

Comment: Is this WinForms? Are you setting the `ListView.View = View.Details;?` You will have to a) decide and b) calculate what shall happen with the Columns left to the new one..!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a constructor overload available to do this

```
listView1.Columns.Add("x", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
```

Read here for further details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ksz7ce2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will only center the content, not the column.